# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Chapter 9 Failing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi i'm a newbie to Rails and I've managed to get to the end of Chapter 9 in Hartl. I have 3 failing tests to complete the Chapter.

Terminal returns this:

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/
..........................................F...................................FF.

Failures:

1) authentication authorization as non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the  Users#destroy action 
 Failure/Error: before { delete user_path(user) }
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:110:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) delete links as an admin user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
   expected link "delete" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:145:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
 Failure/Error: expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link with title, id or text 'delete' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_link'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:147:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.87 seconds
81 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:111 # authentication authorization as   non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:145 # delete links as an admin user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:146 # delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
```

Here's my authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "authentication" do
subject { page }
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

describe "signin page" do
before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
 end

describe "with valid information" do
  before { sign_in user }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

  it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
  end
end

describe "authorization" do

describe "for non-signed-in users" do

  describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
    before do
      visit edit_user_path(user)
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    describe "after signing in" do

      it "should render the desired protected page" do
        page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
      end
    end
  end
 end

  describe "in the Users controller" do

    describe "visiting the edit page" do
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    end

    describe "submitting to the update action" do
      before { put user_path(user) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end

  describe "visiting the user index" do
      before { visit users_path }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    end

 end

 describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
    before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
end

describe "as non-admin user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { sign_in non_admin }

  describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
    before { delete user_path(user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }        
  end
end
end
end
```

And my user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "index" do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

before do
  sign_in user
  visit users_path
end

it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

describe "pagination" do

  it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

  it "should list each user" do
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
    end
  end
 end
end

describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }    
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end

  describe "after submission" do
    before { click_button submit }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do

  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"        
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving a user" do
    before { click_button submit }

    let(:user) { User.find_by_email("user@example.com") }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
 end
end

describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
end

describe "page" do
  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }

  it { should have_content('error') }
  it { should_not have_content('Password digest') }
end

describe "with valid information" do
  let(:new_name) { "New Name" }
  let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
  before do
    fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
    fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
    fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Save changes"
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
  specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
  specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
end
end
end

describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end
end
```

I'm really not sure whats going wrong here, as I've really tried to be faithful to the tutorial. Any ideas? Thanks Simon.

Comment: How is your `index` view from Users? Could you also paste it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are receiving the following message:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
```

You have to create the `destroy` action in your `UsersController`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  .
  .
  .

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'User was deleted with success.'
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

And create the links to be able to delete each user.

In your `app/views/users/index.html.erb', you should have something like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<p><%= link_to user.name, user_path(user), method: delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Problem still there. Exactly the same.

Comment: Managed to remove the first fail - the users controller one. The 2nd and 3rd fail are still there.